# Get the map overlay marker icon during onTap

Tags: android

I'm using an ItemizedOverlay containing a list of OverlayItems to display markers on top of a MapView.  My problem is that when an OverlayItem uses the default marker defined for the overlay, its getMarker() method returns null.  Is there another way I can get that marker image?  I'd like to see if I can animate it during onTap().

I'm showing a bunch of markers on the map, many of which use the same image, so I thought it best to make use of the overlay's default image to save memory.  For this app it's possible there could be more than 100 markers displayed for a given overlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of different ways how to address this. I'm showing the simplest one I know, if it don't solves your problem, let me know.

```
public class MyItemizedNewOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayNewItem> {

    private ArrayList<OverlayNewItem> myOverlays ;
    Drawable defaultMarker;
    Context context;


    public MyItemizedNewOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        this.defaultMarker = defaultMarker;
        this.context = context;
        myOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayNewItem>();
        populate();
    }
   . . .      
}
```

With this you can use the default marker in your code for the onTap()